# I am tring to create a vue project; but it straight away throws an error

Tags: vue.js

When I try to create a vueJs project. It throws the following Error.

```
 vue create client
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'cmd-shim'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\91989\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\util\linkBin.js
- C:\Users\91989\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\util\setupDevProject.js
- C:\Users\91989\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\Creator.js
- C:\Users\91989\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\create.js
- C:\Users\91989\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin\vue.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\91989\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\util\linkBin.js:10:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\91989\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\lib\\util\\linkBin.js',
    'C:\\Users\\91989\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\lib\\util\\setupDevProject.js',
    'C:\\Users\\91989\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\lib\\Creator.js',
    'C:\\Users\\91989\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\lib\\create.js',
    'C:\\Users\\91989\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\bin\\vue.js'
  ]
}
```

I tried to find a solution ; but could find one.
I am using version 3.0.0-beta.9.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: This usually occurs when there is an issue with either your node or npm installations, Try updating node.js and npm to resolve the issue which has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed node
Make sure you have installed vue-cli (

> npm install -g @vue/cli

)

then run

```
vue create (project name)
```